# Typescript EWS Loop Multiple Usercalendar

Tags: typescript, exchangewebservices

I want to fetch all Appointments from an Online Exchange for several users.

For one single user this is not a problem.

For this I used TypeScript and the EWS API from [ts ews api](https://github.com/gautamsi/ews-js-api-browser).

Now I tried to adapt the single user solution to several users.

This user get stored in an array. So I loop over the array and for each User call the exchange to get the Appointments.

```
this.exchangeUsers.forEach((userObj) => {
    const resultObservables = [];//Collect Observable Results in an Array

    calView = new CalendarView(new DateTime(view.start), new DateTime(view.end));// Create Calender View Exchange Web Service
    calView.PropertySet = new PropertySet(AppointmentSchema.Subject, AppointmentSchema.Start, AppointmentSchema.End, AppointmentSchema.IsAllDayEvent);

    calfolder = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, new Mailbox(userObj.mail));

    this.exch.FindAppointments(calfolder, calView).then(
      (liAppointments) => {
        console.log(liAppointments);
      }
    );

  });
```

But I get only a single log in the console. But there should be 4 cause this.exchangeUsers contains 4 Objects.

I know that the loop doesn't wait for the promises to resolve, so maybe every promise got the reference of the last user in the array, but than shouldn't there be 4 entries in the console log ?

Answer (score 0):

after a few more Days of research and testing i found the solution.

I want to share this, just in case somone else got a similiar Problem.

The code was edited by myself into the following :

```
for (let iUser = 0; iUser < this.exchangeUsers.length; iUser++) {
    let calView = new CalendarView(new DateTime(view.start), new DateTime(view.end));// Create Calender View Exchange Web Service
    calView.PropertySet = new PropertySet(AppointmentSchema.Subject, AppointmentSchema.Start, AppointmentSchema.End, AppointmentSchema.IsAllDayEvent);

    let calfolder = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, new Mailbox(this.exchangeUsers[iUser].mail));

    await this.exch.FindAppointments(calfolder, calView).then(
      (liAppointments) => {
        console.log(liAppointments);

      }
    ).catch(
      (err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
```

**Explanation:**

I had to make the Api Exchange Calls 1 by 1 in squence.
It wasn't possible for me to get this work with parallel calls.

To make the calls squential u have to wait for one call to be completly done.

For this we use the keyword **await** . This will suspends the execution until the promise gets resolved.

You can only user **await** in **Asynchronous Functions**. To tell Typescript that a Function is asynchronous you have to add the keyword **async** in front of the function declaration.

You can read more about this [here](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/async-await.html)

Furthermore i had to use this in an normal for loop. The for each loop itself create a function but even if i add the async / await keywords to this i can't manage to get it worked.

I hope i can save some time for somone with this answer.

If someone knows a more elegant way to do this, fell free to share your knowledge with us.